# python write a function that do something like 1234 -> 1.23k

Tags: python

i want to write a function that do something like 1234 -> 1.23k and i cant solve this error
function:

```
def money_unit(money):
    money = float(money)

    if money >= 1000000000000000000000000:
        money = ( format( money , '.2f' ) / 1000000000000000000000000 )
        money = str( money ) + 'Sa'
    elif money >= 1000000000000000000000 :
        money = ( format( money , '.2f' ) / 1000000000000000000000 )
        money = str( money ) + 'Si'
    elif money >= 1000000000000000000:
        money = ( format( money , '.2f' ) / 1000000000000000000 )
        money = str( money ) + 'Qa'
    elif money >= 1000000000000000:
        money = ( format( money , '.2f' ) / 1000000000000000 )
        money = str( money ) + 'Qi'
    elif money >= 1000000000000:
        money = ( format( money , '.2f' ) / 1000000000000 )
        money = str( money ) + 'T'
    elif money >= 1000000000:
        money = ( format( money , '.2f' ) / 1000000000 )
        money = str( money ) + 'B'
    elif money >= 1000000:
        money = ( format( money , '.2f' ) / 1000000 )
        money = str( money ) + 'M'
    elif money >= 1000:
        money = str.format( money , "{:. 2f}" ) / 1000
        money = str( money ) + 'K'

    return money
```

and when i input a nummber with 4 digits or more(when it actualy do something) the error close that
error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\treed\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\pythaon - Copy.py", line 91, in <module>
    print(money_unit(input()))
  File "C:\Users\treed\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\pythaon - Copy.py", line 78, in money_unit
    money = str.format( money , "{:. 2f}" ) / 1000
TypeError: descriptor 'format' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'float' object

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The [tag:pygame] tag is only for questions about the [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library, but not for questions about writing a game with the Python language.

Comment: You seem to be using str.format inappropriately. Use f-strings. Check this out:- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Try `round((money / 1000), 2)` instead of `str.format(...)`. That should round it up and then you have the line to add the `K`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using str.format inappropriately. f-strings are the preferred mechanism for this kind of work.

You can also significantly reduce your runtime code by using a control structure.

Something like this:

```
CONTROL = [
    (1000000000000000000000000, 'Sa'),
    (1000000000000000000000, 'Si'),
    (1000000000000000000, 'Qa'),
    (1000000000000000, 'Qi'),
    (1000000000000, 'T'),
    (1000000000, 'B'),
    (1000000, 'M'),
    (1000, 'K')
    ]

def money_unit(money):
    money = float(money)
    for m, s in CONTROL:
        if money >= m:
            return f'{money/m:.2f}{s}'
    return f'{money:.2f}'

print(money_unit(1234))
```

**Output:**

```
1.23K
```

Answer (score 0):

There are better efficient ways of achieving what you are doing. Also you are changing the original parameter passed from integer to string which works but just wanted to point out...but regardless try following

```
money_str= f"{money/1000:.2f}K"
    
money_str= f"{money/1000000:.2f}M"
```

etcc..

Answer (score 0):

I once had to write a function for this as well, to convert numbers to a human readable format. It is a small function and uses the standard math library for its calculations.

```py
from math import log, floor

def human_format(number: float) -> str:
    units = ["", "K", "M", "B", "T", "Qi", "Qa", "Si", "Sa"]
    k = 1000.0
    magnitude = int(floor(log(number, k)))
    return "%.2f%s" % (number / k**magnitude, units[magnitude])
```